# Android - Automatically delete inactive users from Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I like to automatically delete the user authentication and user info in the database if they have not logged in for say,a month or a year. This is to prevent inactive accounts from taking up space in Firebase.

Is there any way to do that.

Comment: Add a timestamp type field to the user Object, then write a function that listen to that field and check whether is inactive or not.

Answer (score 4):

You will need two things:

1. Create a way to identify old user accounts. You can store a timestamp in your database that records the time of last activity of that user.
2. Write some backend code to query for and delete the accounts.

#1 might require some code in your app to write the current time every time the user launches the app.

#2 requires that you use use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to [delete user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) that you discover using a query for data that you created in #1.

If you do not have data from #1, you will have to [list all user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) using the admin SDK, then figure out which ones need to be deleted.